# AFHTTPClient postPath return AFHTTPRequestOperation instead of AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking

When i request data from server with AFHHTPClient this way:

```
[[NetworkHelper sharedHelper] postPath:path parameters:parameters] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [operation class]);
                NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject class]);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
```

I got this:

```
2012-10-10 13:24:36.881 MyApp[4635:c07] AFHTTPRequestOperation
2012-10-10 13:24:36.881 MyApp[4635:c07] NSConcreteData
```

I tried to force `application/json` content-type in server's response, but i still got `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

But if i use this:

```
[[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }] start];
```

I got JSON responce i need.

What should i do to get JSON response with AFHTTPClient?

**UPDATE:**

I add `NSLog(@"%@",[self.response MIMEType]);` in `- (BOOL)hasAcceptableContentType` method in `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class and i recieve

```
2012-10-11 09:48:25.052 MyApp[3339:3803] application/json
```

but i still get `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set AFHTTPRequestOperation:acceptableContentTypes:

```
+ (NSSet *)acceptableContentTypes {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", nil];
}
```

Comment: how i should do this? :) i tried to put it in my NetworkHelper class implementation, but it didn't called, so i force call it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You must implement it in your AFHTTPRequestOperation subclass (like it did in AFJSONRequestOperation) or directly to AFHTTPRequestOperation [Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/ZJFMRcvZl6n)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem that I suspect may have something to do with the way AFJSONRequestOperation handles responses.

I've dispatched the exact same request using AFJSONRequestOperation using the NSMutableURLRequest returned from [AFHTTPClient clientRequestWithMethod] and constructing my own NSMutableURLRequest and each has a response with a different mime type — the one from [AFHTTPClient clientRequestWithMethod] indicates text/plain; the one from NSMutableURLRequest constructed "by hand" is text/json.

I've mentioned this here in this question:

[AFNetworking with AFHTTPClient with AFJSONRequestOperation // MIME-Type Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182980/afnetworking-with-afhttpclient-authenticating-with-gtmoauthauthentication)